# iOS FBLoginView: the user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, ios-simulator

I have included the FBLoginView in my view controller on XCode without any problems. When I press the button in the iPhone simulator, I get redirected to facebook on safari, but it gives me an error that reads: the user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration.

The app is set to public in the Facebook dashboard, and it is set up in settings with the bundle id and single sign on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This error are most likely caused by using a Facebook test user account to log into a live (non-sandboxed) Facebook app, Facebook test users are app-specific.
Sign out of Facebook and back in with a test user from the correct app.

There are other options like namespace is missing, secretId etc. but if the first answer is not the problem then my guess it's probably something with the app settings in FB.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this problem
my fault was because I create a "**Test User**" but the test user I was created is Test User for Facebook Security, not Test User App. So the solution for me is:
**First:** 
Go into your app on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ 

And then go into your APP and you can see the App Dashboard. 
[image]

**Second:**
Click on **Roles** and Click on **Test Users** and then you gonna see this board. 
[image]
**Third:**
Click on **Add** button to add Test User, and you gonna see this board like below: 
[image]

Select **Authorize Test Users for This App?** to Yes
And **login Permission** I set **email** because I want to get email from Test User and the **Age** you can choose depend on your App, and then click on **Create Test Users** 
**Final Step** 
Set the Test User password.[image]

And we're done, now we can use the Test User we created to test on our App, but make sure to sign out the previous account on Safari first. 
I don't really sure if this is the right answer or not, and the question also had been ask for a long time ago, but I decide to answer this question for others who face a problem like this, I hope this helps everyone who faces the same problem. Cheer.